# Replace variables in war file using Ansible

Tags: ansible, war

I am working on Ansible playbook and want to replace the variables present in the war file. The structure is like below:

1. War file is present on the Ansible server where I am invoking the playbook.
2. Under war file there are environment specific variables under a property file.
3. I need to copy this war file on the target machine and in the process I need to replace the variables in it and deploy the war.

I am able to copy the war file and know how to invoke scripts to to the deploy, but I am not sure how to replace the variables in the war file.

I know template module is there which can replace variables inside file and I am using it to the variable replacement for other files, but have no idea whether I can use the same with war file or not.

Comment: You could create a template of your property file, create a temp file out of it and replace the file inside the war with `zip` prior to uploading. Meanwhile, be aware that this will invalidate signature if your war is signed. Moreover, there are a lot of chances that your app lets you override default properties with a custom file you can place somewhere else on the server (check documentation). You would then just have to to push that file after deployment of your app without having to tamper with the original war file.